# Deploying ReactJS app from GitHub to Ubuntu via Actions

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, github, github-actions

My team is working on an NodeJS app with a ReactJS frontend that needs to be deployed on our Ubuntu server. It runs fine locally and it used to run fine on the server until we added a `Router`/`Switch` structure into the `App.js`. Now we get 404 and 502 errors and I'm thinking of adding some GitHub action to automate the deployment process with `npm run build` and all. Ideally, every time we push to GitHub, the app on the server should update without someone having to tunnel in and type something manually. Can anyone suggest a ready-made YAML file for that purpose? How would we trigger it on our Ubuntu server? Would we run it under `nginx` (like now) or `apache`?